Build simple cpp file with NDK without android studio
How to build a simple helloworld code written in c++ with android ndk:
code example I want to build:
https://github.com/Ylarod/ndk-vscode
NDK that I downloaded on windows:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads
which steps I have to make to build it from terminal?
simple aswner of steps to compile

You can build and install, using below commands.
After input "make install", you might find exec file in installed directory
cd {your project path}
mkdir build
mkdir installed
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../installed \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE={your-ndk-path}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a ../
cmake --build . -j 4
make install

